# MultiValueDictKeyError while trying to add image to my blog post

Tags: python, django, blogs

I am trying to add image to my blog post but when i added this to my code

image = request.Post['image']

And i keep getting errors.

Comment: When posting questions, please include a minimal example that people can copy and run themselves.

Comment: Also be sure to include the complete traceback and error message.

Comment: My bad, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
 def upload_file(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, **request.FILES**)
            if form.is_valid():
                handle_uploaded_file(**request.FILES['image']**)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
        else:
            form = UploadFileForm()
        return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It means that key 'image' does not exist.
Try this:

```
if 'image' in request.FILES:
    image = request.FILES['image']
```

Answer (score 0):

try, request.FILES.get('your_image_field_name')